# connecting joomla to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I install mysql in lamp under Centos with user root and no password.
So i have a joomla website and I put all of it under the htdocs in lamp folder.
I edited configuration file for to use mysql

```
$host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'spilet_en';
$user = 'root';
```

but it said: Database Error: Unable to connect to the database:Could not connect to MySQL

I see the database in phpMyAdmin. and I log in to it with root user name. but it doesn't work.
what should I do? 
It seems that joomla uses on other user_name/. How i can log the user name that joomla tries to connect with that?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure MySQL database run and works correctly. In general default installation mysql  should be no password. You can test it from shell:

```
# mysql -u root
```

Better if you set the root password.
If that run correctly you should connect mysql easily with php. :)

Comment: my mysql is run and i check it with lampp status. either i login to the dabase with "-u root -p ". every thing with mysql is ok. but not about joomla

Answer (score 0):

I checked my joomla's configuation file

My variable database name is so different with your variable.

This my variable

```
var $host = 'localhost';
var $user = 'root';
var $db = '';
```

Pls, check again.